FastAPIでの型エラー
FastAPIでのアプリ作成を行い、uvicornの起動を行なったところ、以下のエラーが出力されています。
TypeError: Annotated[t, ...]: t must be a type. Got <module 'shemas.aaa' from 'ファイルパス'

ここで該当のモジュールを確認したのですが、typingを利用している部分がなく、なぜエラーになるかがわからない状態です。
このエラーの解消方法についてご存知の方いればご教授いただけませんでしょうか。
以下、該当モジュール
from pydantic import BaseModel
from schemas.a1 import A1
from schemas.a2 import A2
from typing import Optional

class Base(BaseModel):
   a1 : Optional[A1]
   a2 : Optional[A2]

class Advanced(BaseModel):
   advanced_list : list[Base] 


エラーはTracebackを省略せず、コピー&ペーストで正確に引用しましょう。コードの引用が「該当モジュール」となっていますが、実際のファイル名はなんですか? 「あなたがなにを該当モジュールと考えているのか?」は伝わりません。uvicornコマンドを実行している時のカレントディレクトリからみた相対ファイル名でよいので書き記す必要があります
